# Showing popup info after click to marker

Tags: javascript, openlayers, popup, markers

This is my code with some marker. I would like to show square with marker informations after click to some marker on map like [there](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.3.0_simpleMultipleMarkerExample.html).

I get piece of js code from this page, write to my code and tried it. But doesn´t work with info squares.

Can you help me to choose correct part of code from [page](http://view-source:http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.3.0_simpleMultipleMarkerExample.html) for showing an info square about the marker?

For example with text "Hello world!" after clicking a marker.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Working with Openlayers</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
 <!-- Openlayers CSS file--> 
 
 <style type="text/css">
  #map{
   width:80%;
   height:600px;
   margin: 10px;
  }

 </style>
 <!--Basic styling for map div, 
 if height is not defined the div will show up with 0 px height  --></head>
<body>

 <center>   
 <div id="map">
  <div id="popup"></div>
 </div>
 </center>
 <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- Openlayesr JS fIle -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="map_index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- Our map file -->
 
 </body>
</html>
```

**index.js** (Just isn´t correctly running)

```
var baseMapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [ baseMapLayer],
  view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-74.0061,40.712]), 
          zoom: 12 //Initial Zoom Level
        })
});

var marker = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
    ol.proj.fromLonLat([-74.006,40.7127])
     ),  // Cordinates of New York's City Hall
});

var marker2 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
    ol.proj.fromLonLat([40.7127, -74.006])
     ),  // Cordinates of New York's City Hall
});

marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon( ({
    color: '#ffcd46',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    src: 'dot.png'
  }))
}));

marker2.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon( ({
    color: '#cdff46',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    src: 'dot.png'
  }))
}));

//function for show marker info
      map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        var name = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature) {
          return 'Hello world';
          
        })
       
          container.style.display="block";
          var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
          content.innerHTML = "Hello";
          overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
       
    
      });
      map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel) ? 'pointer' : '';
      });
//to there



 
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [marker, marker2]
});

var markerVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
});  
map.addLayer(markerVectorLayer);
```

Comment: Have you defined `overlay`, `container` and `content`? Is `overlay` added to the map?

Comment: Please how to do it? Thank's

Comment: Look at the source for the example you linked http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.3.0_simpleMultipleMarkerExample.html

Comment: Yes, I saw this source and get some piece of code but probably soemething miss in my code. I need in my page with markers...